# Android: How to do (automated) functional testing of Location Services

Tags: android, junit

The app that I am working, is driven by Location Services. Driving with phone hooked to laptop is not always practical (and getting complex).

How would I write automated functional test for my app (googling shows UI related testing)? I understand that I need to inject values into following callback (since my app is driven by Location Manager)

```
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
```

In a java application, I would create a unit that would have instance of my application and invoke the methods. But,
a) How would I do it for Android App (where there is no main method and everything is driven by onCreate())
b) How does it change, if above functionality is part of Android Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where we work, we use PowerMockito. I'm not a super fan of it, but I totally understand your frustration with unit tests. Here's a decent tutorial for the topic: http://www.johnmullins.co/blog/2015/02/15/beginners-guide-to-using-mockito-and-powermockito-to-unit-test-java/

Basically, what PowerMockito lets you do is write a bunch of Powermock unit tests. Those tests are going to let you mock the responses, and let you test your code. You can even manually call "onLocationChanged".

The reason I don't like PowerMockito  is that that means you have to act like the Android OS. You can make dummy location responses and test to see if your code does the right thing, but it's much harder to test the code with field conditions. If a particular phone has an issue with the locations its returning, PowerMock is never going to help you catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Use MockLocationProvider in android genymotion emulator.

See below link:-
https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/